# Page Unresponsive While Rendering a Same React-virstuso Component with different data set

Tags: accordion, react-functional-component, react-18, react-virtuoso

i have a customized react-virtuso table with a each row have a accordions like expand collapse row , i splitted the code in 3 different files i have a data set in one file then mapping the data set in to the react-virtuso , when i am running my code while rendering i am getting page unresponsive

i am tried with scroll functionality each table will render while a user scoll alone but also i wil navigate through the navbar for the each components at the time when i am doing like a scroll rendering , for example i have 30 table component with different data set now i am scroll to the 2nd one then navigate to the last one by clicking in the navbar at the time the table not rendered.
i need without scroll rendering i want to render all the tables in the first time.

```
 const handleScroll = () => {
    const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
    if (container) {
      const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = container;
      if (scrollHeight - (scrollTop + clientHeight) < 100) {
        loadNextItem();
      }
    }
  };
     const loadNextItem = (item) => {
      const nextIndex = loadedItems.length;
       // Calculate the next index based on the current length of loadedItems
      if (nextIndex < leftNavigationFields.length) {
        setLoadingIndex(nextIndex);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLoadedItems((prevLoadedItems) => {
            const newLoadedItems = [...prevLoadedItems];
            newLoadedItems[nextIndex] = nextIndex; // Assign the nextIndex value to the corresponding index
            return newLoadedItems;
          });
          setLoadingIndex(-1);
        }, 500); // Delay of 1 second
      }

    };
  <div ref={scrollContainerRef} style={{ height: '94vh', overflow: 'auto' , scrollBehavior:"smooth" }} onScroll={handleScroll}>
{navigationfield.map((item , index) =>{
const isLoadedAndChecked = loadedItems.includes(index) && item.checked === true && item.fieldName!=="Job Details";
                if (isLoadedAndChecked ) {
                  return (
                    <div id={item.fieldName}>
                    <Suspense fallback={<div style={{ marginLeft: '150px', marginTop: '40px', color: 'red' }} key={isLoadedAndChecked}>Loading</div>} >
                      <TableVirtuoso
                       itemName={item.fieldName}
                       icon={item.icon}
                       columns={item.columns}
                       listData={item.data}
                       checkbox={true}
                       hover={true}
                       isOpened={isOpened}
                     />
                   </Suspense>
                   </div>
       
                 );
               } else if (loadingIndex === index) {
                 return (
                   <div style={{ marginLeft: '120px', marginTop: '40px', color: 'red' }} key={item.fieldName}>Loading</div>
                 );
               }
               return null;
       
          })}
</div>
```

inside the navigationfield i have a different dataset now i am rendering this my page gettting unresponive i need a solution without scroll functionallity